# Total elapsed CPU time of a process started with Popen

Tags: python, python-3.x, process, timing

I can get the total elapsed CPU time of the current process using `time.process_time()`. However, I spawn other processes, and I need to get the total CPU time used up by the child processes.

Since the child processes do not always execute python, I can't really just insert `time.process_time()` in them and pass that information back to the parent. (Even if I could, it would be rather annoying.)

So I guess the best solution would be to measure the elapsed time of an arbitrary process using some system call (hopefully accessible from python); of course, I'll have to do it right after the child process completes but before the information about it gets destroyed by the OS (in other words, I have to catch it in its zombie state).

Ideally, I'm looking for a solution for both Linux and Windows, but if it's only for Linux, it's fine.

Comment: [**`psutil`**](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) will give you everything you need.

Comment: @PeterWood yes, thanks!